# How to change font size in non-sp scale?

Tags: java, android, textview, resize

I'm trying to animate font scale of `TextView` (e.g from 14sp to 22sp), but it scale only by 1 sp and it changing ansty. Don't know how to explain more correctly, but also it looks like `TextView` laggs when change size but it isn't.

I've tried to use standart method `setTextSize(float size)` and also `setTextSize(int units, float size)` in pixels, but nothing changed. I've tried `scaleX()` and `scaleY()` methods too, but they are difficult to fit in defined sp size.

```java
ValueAnimator sizeAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(size, sizeEnd);
sizeAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
```

I expected smooth changing of scale like if I use `scaleX()` and `scaleY()`, but it still scales "stairly"

Comment: You won't be able to run smooth animation on font size like that. Your best bet is using largest font size in the first place, then running scaleX/Y animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel), I came up with new idea to set font size to `sizeEnd` and then set scaleX=scaleY=`size/sizeEnd` of `textView`, where `size` is the size that was which should have `textView` and `sizeEnd` is the size which should be at the end of animation (target size).
In my case it works, but it is not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `layoutparams` of your `textview` as well

```
 @Override
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    int val = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
    layoutParams.height = val;
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
 }
```